# Best way of recording rapidly updating data (Android)

Tags: android, caching, onchange

What is the best way of recording rapidly updating data in Android?

In my specific example I am trying to record various data tidbits whenever (acceleration) onSensorChanged fires, which is often. It's fine for some quick processing and displaying, but anything more (plotting or recording data) makes it rather slow. It's worth noting that I'm storing it in a variable and not to file.

You are advised to do as little as possible in an onSensorChanged, so I tried the following:

- In an `IntentService`: Fetch the rest of the data you want to record and store all of it in a variable. *Result*: Even though an intent service executes in its own thread, only one can run at a time. Data thus seemed to come in quicker than it could be processed and would end up with a long queue of data to be processed, giving a long and constant stream of GC_FOR_ALLOC. Ultimately making it a bad choice
- In an `AsyncTask` fetch the extra data you want to record and then start an `IntentService` for recording it to a variable. 
  *Result*: Pretty much the same as above.

Overall both of these methods were actually performing significantly *worse* than just doing the extra data fetching and recording in the onChanged, as well as consuming significantly more power. I haven't been able to find any concrete advice on rapid data storage. Would a buffer or cache perhaps be more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging and attempts at using different data structures for storing the rapidly updating data, it turns out that using the `IntentService` works reasonably well. Changing from an `ArrayList` with O(n) for adding new elements, to a custom `LinkedList` that just appended new values to the end with O(1) made a massive difference. As the LL is able to process the data so much quicker, the problem of a huge queue of pending values to record basically disappears.